# how to avoid too many publishes error in Mqtt?

Tags: java, protocols, mqtt

We are using mqtt protocol to publish messages through a java app.
This app is being run through an RPI computer with limited processing speed and ram.
On the mqtt we are publishing a status message every 20 seconds
This message is published properly for a few hours but then it starts publishing 4 status message at a time and sometimes gives an error too many publishes in process.
It would be helpful if someone can explain why this multiple publishes are happening and how we could avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information: Which java library are you using? Can you post the code that you are using?

Comment: We are using mqttv3 paho library but sorry cant upload code cause of security policies

Comment: Wich JVM are you using on RPI? The new Java8 is an alpha release and can have weird behaviours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting this message due to making continuous publish on MQTT on a low memory environment, RPi (Raspberry Pi) being equipped with 512 Mb of RAM, may cause this problem.
One solution is to set Quality of Service QoS as 0 (zero) for this publish. This can be achieved using method

```
MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
message.setQos(0);
....
```

Setting QoS 0 does not acknowledges transmitted message, hence saves memory. For more information on QoS, please check following link http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/qos.html

Good Luck ...

Comment: The little memory maybe explains the error message, but I would only set the publish to QoS 0, if your PI is connected over a reliable connection, for example over a cable. Otherwise you are loosing the advantages of MQTT. It totally depends on your specific use case.

Comment: As Chritian says, setting QoS to 0 is not a good solution here - you sacrifice reliability of your messages for what should be proper memory management in your application. It is a shame this answer has been accepted.

Comment: It is only a status message so quality is not an issue